# VBA Excel: calculating

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub FallOrSpringsemester()

Dim enrollPeriod As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim text As String


Set w = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
w.Name = "oldest Students"

Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(1, 1) = "Student_ID"
Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(1, 2) = "Enroll_Date"
Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(1, 3) = "Program_Type_Name"
Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(1, 4) = "Enrollment_Period"

LastRow = Worksheets("Base").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

Worksheets("oldest students").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12)

Worksheets("oldest students").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4)

Worksheets("oldest students").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 11)
```

Above this coding I ofc have my dimed variables and also coding for creating a new sheet.

I have trouble with this part as it will no do the calculations and tells me there is an error 
"13": type miss match

```
    If enrollPeriod Mod 2 = 0 Then
    Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(i, 2) = "Spring"
    enrollPeriod = enrollPeriod + 1
    Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(i, 1) = 2018 - ((138 - enrollPeriod) / 2)

    Else

    Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(i, 2) = "Fall"

    Worksheets("oldest Students").Cells(i, 1) = 2018 - ((138-enrollPeriod) / 2)

   End if  
   Next

   End Sub
```

Comment: `enrollPeriod` is defined as String,  but should be probably Long, there is also missing `End if` statement

Comment: Why is one Worksheets("oldest Students") range .Cells(i, **1**) for the calc and the other is .Cells(i, **2**)

Comment: Ohh yeah I fixed that later on but thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

I think enrollPperiod should be an integer... that should fix it

Comment: that did help, however, for some reason now it skips the first part of my if statement ?

Comment: What is the initial value for it? If it is not set up Mod 2 would not return 1.

Comment: @MathiasThrige generally people check whether number mod 2 = 0, not 1

Comment: @marcuccuboy2 that did help for the first time it the code runs over it, however, after that it starts skipping it again - also the mod function is supposed to see if the enrollPeriod is an odd or even number

Comment: It is because you never increment the value of enrollPeriod, in the first run  it is set to 0. So It enters into the first part of the "if" then it increments (adds 1 to it) --> it becomes 1 then in the next run it steps in the else part - and there it always stays one... therefore it will return Fall Fall Fall in each run from then.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but probably your enrollPeriod value should also come from the "Base" sheet

Comment: I got it to work right!! Thanks for the help everyone, much appreciated!